# How to enable MediaWiki's new Visual Editor?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I've been using the default MediaWiki's built-in WikiEditor, but I found about this: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor:Test

I can't find where it says what do I need to do to get it running. Do I need some configuration properties on my `LocalSettings.php` file?

Comment: I think you would be more likely to get a good answer from the folks over on Superuser.

Comment: Or rather, [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I don't think the VE team has posted installation instructions but the code is available: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/extensions/VisualEditor.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/master;hb=master. I'd actually like to try this out too. Might be a good question for a bounty if no one gets back to you.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some instructions: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor.

You also need to install a Parsoid server. Here are instructions for that: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid#Getting_started.